# Peaks in Load of Firebase RT Database cause my applications to slow down

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a dashboard in which I use Firebase Real Time Database. I have also a backend that publishes output to the front-end, which runs in batches. Every time when there is a batch, I notice that the Load peaks to almost 100% (most of it is writing but there is also some considerable loading). This is causing my front-end dashboard to slow down.

My question is what I could do to avoid this issue? Is there a way to scale the Load up, such that its less likely to approach the 100%? What is the Firebase recommended way to handle this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of spiky load is indeed commonly caused by backend processes that run in batches.

The Firebase backend storage layer runs pretty much as a single threaded process for each database, handling each (read or write) request from clients in turn. So while it is processing one request, any other requests are awaiting their turn.

This means that if you have a particularly large read or write request, it keeps other clients from getting their requests served. For this reason you'll want to take care to divide the interactions with the database (especially from the backend process) into small operations as to not interfere with the other clients.

If the backend process also needs to read a considerable part of the database for its work, consider if you can make it read from a backup of the database instead of the from the live database. The backups are made out-of-band, so don't interfere with clients, so if you *can* use the backup as the source for reading the data, it will significantly reduce the read load that the backend process causes.